# Why is xsl:value-of behaving completely different depending on the xsl:stylesheet version?

Tags: xpath, xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, xpath-2.0

Looking at this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    root
    <child>
        child 1
        <grandchild>
            grandchild 1
        </grandchild>
        <yetanothergrandchild>
            yetanothergrandchild 1
        </yetanothergrandchild>
    </child>
    <child>
        child 2
        <grandchild>
            grandchild 2
        </grandchild>
        <yetanothergrandchild>
            yetanothergrandchild 2
        </yetanothergrandchild>
    </child>
</root>
```

and that XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output media-type="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <fo:root>

            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple"
                                       page-height="29.7cm"
                                       page-width="21cm"
                                       margin-top="1cm"
                                       margin-bottom="2cm"
                                       margin-left="2.5cm"
                                       margin-right="2.5cm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent="3cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

                    <fo:block font-size="12pt"
                              font-family="sans-serif"
                              line-height="15pt"
                              space-after.optimum="3pt"
                              text-align="justify">
                        <xsl:value-of select="root/child/grandchild"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="root/child/yetanothergrandchild"/>
                    </fo:block>

                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I put the xsl:stylesheet version to 1.0, the output is:
grandchild 1 yetanothergrandchild 1

If I put it to 2.0, the output is:
grandchild 1 grandchild 2 yetanothergrandchild 1 yetanothergrandchild 2

Of course, I read already through various lists of differences in between XSL T 1 and 2 but I cannot find any hint of a change which could cause that.

Can somebody tell me how and why that behaves that differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#backwards and then https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#incompatibilities saying

> J.1.3 Backwards Compatibility Behavior Some XSLT constructs behave
> differently under XSLT 2.0 depending on whether backwards compatible
> behavior is enabled. In these cases, the behavior may be made
> compatible with XSLT 1.0 by ensuring that backwards compatible
> behavior is enabled (which is done using the [xsl:]version attribute).
>
> These constructs are as follows:
>
> If the xsl:value-of instruction has no separator attribute, and the
> value of the select expression is a sequence of more than one item,
> then under XSLT 2.0 all items in the sequence will be output, space
> separated, while in XSLT 1.0, all items after the first will be
> discarded.
>
> ...

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 1.0 the `xsl:value-of` instruction returns the string-value of the **first** node in the selected node-set.

In XSLT 2.0 the instruction returns the value of **every** node in the selected sequence, separated by a space or by the string specified in the `separator` attribute.

These are my formulations, the specs are more difficult to follow.